# Include ITU-T software in an Apache 2.0 licensed project

Tags: apache-2.0

[ITU-T Recommendation T.88](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.88/en) [includes software](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.88-201808-I/en). The software seems to be behind a paywall today, but I downloaded it 2 years ago when it wasn't. The accompanying copyright notice says the following:

> ICT Link (contact: Shigetaka Ogawa; address: 1-24-5 Komaba Meguru, Tokyo, Japan; Tel. +81 3 5465 0904; email: s_ogawa@mug.biglobe.ne.jp (hereinafter the "Software Copyright Holder") holds or has the right to license copyright with respect to the accompanying software (hereinafter the "Software"). The Software Copyright Holder hereby grants to you an irrevocable, non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free, sub-licensable copyright licence to prepare derivative works of (including translations, adaptations, alterations), the Software and reproduce, display, distribute and execute the Software and derivative works thereof, for the limited purposes of: (i) including the Software in a conforming implementation of this ITU Recommendation, (ii) evaluating the Software and any derivative works thereof for inclusion in your implementation of this ITU Recommendation, and (iii) determining whether your implementation conforms to this ITU Recommendation.

Can I include this software in a project I am developing that has an Apache 2.0 license?